# Pyinstaller flush input

Tags: python-3.x, buffer, pyinstaller

I've a python program which works fine within the Pycharm environment.

I tried compiling it with Pyinstalle to a onefile executable.
It works fine, but I see no output till I select it.
I actually casually discovered this using ctrl+A.

I tried adding flush=True to print, but with no results.

The program starts with a simple print and even that first one won't show up.

Any ideas?

EDIT: It also seems like that this "buffering" stops execution, but I'm not completely sure of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Instead of

```
print("", flush=True)
```

solved the problem for me.